# Firebase CLI console: Cannot find module @google-cloud/tasks

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have dependency to Cloud Tasks in my **index.js** file: `const {CloudTasksClient} = require("@google-cloud/tasks")`. But when I try to deploy my cloud function using Tasks, it's complete with the error: `Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/tasks'`. Then I ran again `npm install @google-cloud/tasks` and console say no errors, it looks as succeed. When I check my **package.json** and **package-lock.json** files, they do not contain anything about @google-cloud/tasks. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably ran `npm install` in the wrong directory.  Be sure to change to the directory where package.json exists before running that command.

Comment: make sure to do it from functions directory